# Connect QuickBooks with Foundry

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-data-connection

Has anyone connected their QuickBooks instance with Foundry? I'm a little unclear on how to setup things on QuickBooks & then on the Foundry side (using the Rest Source) to get the data in. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you contacted Palantir support with the details of how you want to connect to Quickbooks? A member of the team would be happy to help (and the answer would be specific to the security requirements of your organization).

To get you started though, the rest API for the data connector product has full documentation here:
https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/source-types/rest-apis/